# Angular 5 one list push to another list using only row and column index

Tags: javascript, angular5

In angular 5, How can get static listA records using only row column index to ListB .Not using Column headers in component.ts file.Can you help me

```
ListA=[{Id:0,Name:Babu},{Id:1,Name:raju}] // here ListA is static list.
```

new ListB will be in the form of

```
[{A:1,B:Babu},{A:2,B:raju}] // here B column record as ListA Column "Name" record.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array.map function to generate your new array:

```
let listB = listA.map((item) => {A: item.Id, B:item.Name});
```

By the way, unless your Name property values is a variable, you should add quotes around it. Like this:

```
ListA=[{Id:0,Name:"Babu"},{Id:1,Name:"raju"}]
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Id and Name are the excel sheet column headers.If the column header have space (eg: First Name or Employee Id) then how can add this to a list